# how to change multiple function arguments into coffescrpt

Tags: coffeescript

here is the javascript:

```
$inputor.on("keyup.inputor", $.proxy(function(e) {
    var stop_key = e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38
    lookup = !(this.view.isShowing() && stop_key)
    if (lookup) this.lookup()
},this))
```

how can i translate it into coffesscript? the first argument of a function like $.proxy  is  a function and still have a second one.

my solution is assign a variable for the first argument, the function, and poss it to $.proxy. 
but i want a better solution.

coffeescript:

```
??????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the jQuery.proxy function, you could use the CoffeeScript fat arrow `=>` since the context you're trying to use is `this`

```
$inputor.on "keyup.inputor", (e) =>
  stop_key = e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38
  lookup   = !(@view.isShowing() && stop_key)
  @lookup() if lookup
```